# How can I redirect subdomain in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi on my webpage I need redirect if user enter via „https://darkzin.cz/“ to „https://www.darkzin.cz/“.
For this someone help me with ".htaccess" code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.darkzin.cz/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

It works, but now i need subdomain (https://pamatnicek.darkzin.cz/). And here is my problem.

- If I use this "three lines", than works "redirect without www to with www", but I can not access to subdomain. Subdomain url is redirect to homepage.
- If I delete this "three lines", than I can enter to subdomain, but my web works "with www" and "without www" and for that I have duplicate urls.

How can I solved this?

Comment: Should subdomain be redirected or not? If yes, then how?

Comment: Redirection ideally for me:
darkzin.cz => www.darkzin.cz /// pamatnicek.darkzin.cz => www.pamatnicek.darkzin.cz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding domain name, match it from URL itself using `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` and use a back-reference later in rule:

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

`%1` is value we are capturing from capture group in `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]` and using `%1` later in `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I'm dealing with a colleague and it seems to be working. Thank you.